# Laravel PHPExcel - Row Length Limitation Issue (xls)

Tags: php, excel, laravel, phpexcel, xls

Found an interesting issue with Laravel and PHPExcel. Given the code below:

```
\Excel::create("TestingXLS", function($excel){
    $excel->sheet("TestingSheet1", function($sheet){
        $values = [];
        for($i = 1; $i <= 257; $i++){
            $values[] = $i;
        }

        for($j = 1; $j <= 5; $j++){
            $sheet->row($j, $values);
        }
    });
})->download("xls");
```

What this should do is generate an `.xls` document with **5 rows of 257 columns**, but what actually happens is that I end up with **a single row of 256 columns**. Effectively, anything following column 256 (`IW` column index in Excel) and any additional rows following the first are truncated, but I can't figure out why.

Note I've tested with `$i <= 256;` as the first condition, and it generates 5 rows of 256 columns (`IV` column index) with no issue.

I know this can be alleviated by using `->download("xlsx")`, but other requirements in the document I'm generating require that it is an `.xls` file. Also due to client requirements, I can't flip the layout from columns to rows and vice-versa.

Anyone have any ideas on an approach to solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had to solve this by `chunk`ing the columns into a maximum of 256 columns, then creating additional sheets as required:

```
$valuesArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

$valueChunks = collect($valuesArray)->chunk(3); // Using `3` for demo

\Excel::create("TestingXLS", function($excel) use($valueChunks){
    foreach($valueChunks AS $chunkKey => $chunkArray){
        $excel->sheet("TestingSheet".($chunkKey == 0 ? "" : "_".($chunkKey + 1)), function($sheet) use($chunkArray){

            $values = [];
            foreach($chunkArray AS $key => $value){
                $values[] = $value;
            }

            for($j = 1; $j <= 5; $j++){
                $sheet->row($j, $values);
            }
        });
    }
})->download("xls");
```

Using the above code, I end up with:

```
===========================================
|     | TestingSheet    | TestingSheet2   |
===========================================
|     |  A  |  B  |  C  |  A  |  B  |  C  |
-------------------------------------------
|  1  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |
|  2  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |
|  3  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |
|  4  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |
|  5  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |
===========================================
```

Using multiple `$excel->sheet()` functions to handle >= 256 columns isn't ideal, but satisfies the requirement for `.xls` file and displaying all associated data. Testing with a loop for `for($i = 0; $i <= 1000; $i++)` results in 4 Sheets with at most 256 columns; all data intact.

Answer (score 1):

MS Excel has a limit of 256 columns (column IV) for BIFF-format xls files, so it should not be possible to generate a 257-column worksheet using the xls writer

Comment: That's what I figured. I looked up the max column count, and didn't see 256 anywhere, but I was probably looking at `.xlsx` specs. Also, 257 is just an example over 256; there's ~351 columns in the data I'm actually using, so I'll likely be chunking that into multiple sheets to get around this. Thanks for this.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this fix, it will start working. Avoid using two loops inside excel function, it sometimes creates an issue.

```
$values = [];
for($i = 1; $i <= 257; $i++){
   $values[] = $i;
}
\Excel::create("TestingXLS", function($excel)use($values){
    $excel->sheet("TestingSheet1", function($sheet)use($values){
        for($j = 1; $j <= 5; $j++){
            $sheet->row($j, $values);
        }
    });
})->download("xls");
```

Comment: This will not fix it; having a couple loops in a function is not an issue, sorry.